# trigger event from a child but have the parent listen fro it in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have a child trigger a custom event called CHANGED when it is selected but have its parent listen for that event. Is it possible through event bubbling up to the parent

I have a plugin from someone that is called like so.
(#selector).dropdown();

Inside the dropdown it recreates a select list.

```
  <select id="selectBox">
     <option value="0">Select</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
```

Now when one of the li selectors is clicked I want to trigger an event from it like below but have the parent listen for it. Parent meaning the slectBox element.

```
    // INSIDE PLUGIN
    $("li", ul).click(function () {
       $(this).trigger('CHANGED');
    });

   //IN MY PAGE CODE
  $(function(){
       ('#selectBox').dropdown();
       ('#selectBox').bind('CHANGED', update);

       function update(evt){
          alert(evt.target);
       } 
  });
```

Comment: Your JS doesn't match your HTML by the way.  Your "INSIDE PLUGIN" block refers to LI/UL elements...  Perhaps you meant select/option?  Select boxes don't contain LIs.

Comment: Yep sorry about that working too fast and din't mean to put that in there basically ul would be the ul element. the click would happen on the li element

Answer (score 0):

So, I must be missing some context here, but if you can create an event, you know the element names, and you know when you want it performed, why not just add another event handler normally?

In your case:

```
  $(function(){
       $('#selectBox').bind('change', update);

       function update(evt){
          alert(evt.target);
       } 
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qruKH/

Comment: This is true but its a custom plugin that skins the drop-down list. So it hides the original li elements and creates its own list based on the original html. Thats why when the custom list is created in the plugin and one of them is clicked I want to fire a custom event.

Answer (score 0):

That is what the delegate function is for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(DocReady);

    function DocReady()
    {
        $("#selectBox").delegate("option", "click", SelectClicked);
    }

    function SelectClicked()
    {
        alert("You clicked: " + this.text);
    }
```

Comment: What is option? In my plugin I'm triggering the event on the li element. Does the trigger stay the same in the plugin.

Comment: Option is the name of the child elements.  A select parent has several option children.